# App Crashes suddenly crashes in debug-Mode see crash log

Tags: android

I´m working on a app-project, but suddenly it always crashes immediatly. I don´t know the reason. Here the crash log:

```
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lexoffice.android/com.lexoffice.android.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.lexoffice.android.Login.onCreate(Login.java:21)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  ... 11 more
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  ... 26 more
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/activity_login.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f030000
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2053)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:342)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:782)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  ... 29 more
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag ScrollView
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:146)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:129)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2050)
03-24 00:16:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  ... 33 more
```

Comment: Something is wrong here  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/activity_login.xml from color state list

Comment: please post the involved xml resource files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is failing in `onCreate()` when it tries to access one of the `Button` objects defined in your XML file. In my experience, this failure is probably occurring in `findViewById()` when you are specifying the wrong resource id in your `R.id.whatever` value.

If everything checks out, often a complete refresh, clean, and rebuild can fix the problem.

Comment: Hey David! You save my Project. There was an unspecified attribute in the activity_login.xml. It came from the Graphical Layout-Settings. Sometimes it is better to code and not to use wizzards...